# as3 move towards function jitters on Y axis

Tags: actionscript-3

As the title suggests, I've written a move towards function that works perfectly fine, except that it jitters on the Y axis.

### The problem

It happens when the function is operating on the Y axis and the difference between the starting value and the target value is less than that between the starting value and the value to return - meaning that the value has gone past its target. as this point, it's supposed to set the returning value to the target value, but for the most part it's not. Except when it's operating on the x axis, in which case it works fine. It's really strange.

### The code

here's the code I'm using for the function:

```
public static function LookAt(thisX:Number, thisY:Number, targetX:Number, targetY:Number, speed:Number = 0, startRot:Number = 0):Number
{
    // Get the distances between the two parsed points
    var xDif:Number = targetX - thisX;
    var yDif:Number = targetY - thisY;

    // Use a tangent formula to get the rotation to return in radians, then convert to degrees
    var rot:Number = Math.atan2(xDif, yDif) * 180/Math.PI * -1 - 180;

    // If a speed has been parsed
    if (speed != 0)
    {
        // Ensure the parsed starting rotation is between -180 and 180
        while (startRot > 180)
        {startRot -= 360;}
        while (startRot < -180)
        {startRot += 360;}

        // If the rotation previously calculated is less than the parsed starting rotation, 
        // return the starting rotation minus the speed. Otherwise, return the starting rotation
        // plus the speed
        return (rot > startRot) ? startRot + speed : startRot - speed;
    }
    else
    {
        return rot;
    }
}

public static function PointAround (axisPos:Number, angle:Number, speed:Number, axis:String = "x"):Number
{
    // Convert the parsed angle into radians
    var fixedRot = angle * Math.PI / 180;

    // Return the parsed position plus speed multiplied by the sine of the angle in radians for the x axis,
    // or the cosine of the angle in radians for the y axis
    return (axis == "x") ? axisPos + speed * Math.sin(fixedRot) : axisPos + speed * Math.cos(fixedRot) * -1;
}

public static function PointTowards(thisX:Number, thisY:Number, targetX:Number, targetY:Number, speed:Number, axis:String = "x"):Number
{
    // Use the LookAt function to calculate a rotation for later use in this function
    var workingAngle:Number = ExtraMath.LookAt (thisX, thisY, targetX, targetY);
    var toReturn;

    var thisVar:Number = (axis == "x") ? thisX : thisY;
    var targetVar:Number = (axis == "x") ? thisX : thisY;

    toReturn = ExtraMath.PointAround (thisVar, workingAngle, speed);
    // BUGGY LINE
    toReturn = (thisVar >= targetVar && toReturn <= targetVar
                || thisVar <= targetVar && toReturn >= targetVar)
                ? targetVar
                : toReturn;

    return toReturn;
}
```

and here's the code I'm using to test it:

```
public var c:Sprite;

public function TestZone() 
{
    // constructor code
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
}

private function Update (e:Event):void
{
    c.x = ExtraMath.PointTowards(c.x, c.y, stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, 5);
    c.y = ExtraMath.PointTowards(c.x, c.y, stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, 5, "y");
}
```

### things I've tried already

- turning the line into regular a regular if statement with curly brackets and all, and tracing the variables thisY, targetY and toReturn after it has been operated on. the really annoying thing is that it turns out it sometimes actually returns the right number, but then proceeds to bug out again
- Using an absolute value instead of stage.mouseY in testing. bug occurs as usual
- Performing the function on the Y axis before the X axis. no difference
- Changing the condition for setting the variables thisVar and targetVar to (axis != x) and switching the if/else values. do difference

Answer (score 0):

A few things may be causing the problem:

---

```
[LookAt]
return (rot > startRot) ? startRot + speed : startRot - speed;
```

This may cause overshooting. If `rot` is only very slightly different from `startRot`, you are still adding (or subtracting) a full `speed` increment. If the absolute distance between `rot` and `startRot` is less than `speed`, it should return `rot` regardless.

This reduces angular jittering.

---

```
[PointAround]
return (axis == "x") ? axisPos + speed * Math.sin(fixedRot) : axisPos + speed * Math.cos(fixedRot) * -1;
```

Watch out for operator precedence. You are expecting this line to be parsed as

```
(axis == "x") ?
                (axisPos + speed * Math.sin(fixedRot)) :
                (axisPos + speed * Math.cos(fixedRot) * -1);
```

But that may not be the case. The line may instead be interpreted as

```
(
 (axis == "x") ?
                 (axisPos + speed * Math.sin(fixedRot)) :
                  axisPos
)
+ speed * Math.cos(fixedRot) * -1;
```

You can either memorize all precedence rules and make sure you never mistake them, or put parenthesis around to ensure it's doing the right thing. In this case you can simplify the expression to

```
axisPos + speed * (axis == "x" ? Math.sin(fixedRot) ? -Math.cos(fixedRot))
```

---

```
var thisVar:Number = (axis == "x") ? thisX : thisY;
var targetVar:Number = (axis == "x") ? thisX : thisY;
```

So `thisVar` and `targetVar` always have the same value? I don't understand what was supposed to happen here, and nobody seems to reassign those variables later.

---

```
c.x = ExtraMath.PointTowards(c.x, c.y, stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, 5);
c.y = ExtraMath.PointTowards(c.x, c.y, stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, 5, "y");
```

You are changing the position separately in each axis. It may work, but it's harder and error prone. For example

```
c.x = ...PointTowards(c.x ...);
c.y = ...PointTowards(c.x ...);
```

You are changing the value of `c.x` between the calls, so the first call to `PointTowards` see a different point from the second call. That may be the reason why the jittering only happens on the `y` axis. I suggest making a function that deals with box axis at once, or at the very least storing the old values of `c.x` and `c.y`:

```
var oldX:Number = c.x;
var oldY:Number = c.y;
c.x = ExtraMath.PointTowards(oldX, oldY, stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, 5);
c.y = ExtraMath.PointTowards(oldX, oldY, stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, 5, "y");
```

Comment: thanks for answering! setting targetVar to the starting variables was a typo, it's supposed to set it to either targetX or targetY
I forgot to mention that I did try storing the old position values and parsing those in instead, but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I changed the function to return a point object instead of a number and now it works perfectly